# How to iterate an array in Go, starting from the index middle and then continue from index 0?

Tags: arrays, loops, go

My goal is to iterate an array from the middle, and then continue from index 0.

[full code](https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/cipta_integrasi_nusantara_backend/blob/master/calculateage/helper.go)

The current solution is to duplicate the body block

```
    for _, daysInMonth := range daysInMonths[a.Month()-1:] {
        daysDiff -= float64(daysInMonth)
        if daysDiff < 0 {
            daysDiff += float64(daysInMonth)
            break
        }

        monthsDiff += 1
    }
    for _, daysInMonth := range daysInMonths {
        daysDiff -= float64(daysInMonth)
        if daysDiff < 0 {
            daysDiff += float64(daysInMonth)
            break
        }

        monthsDiff += 1
    }
```

Comment: whats the problem? You show a solution, is there anything not working?

Comment: @TheFool I would like to know if Golang can do something like `daysInMonths[9:8]` -> `9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8`

Comment: Use a regular `for` statement, and modulo with `len(daysInMonths)`?

Comment: @JimB could you give an example? I can't imagine it with a module and len(dysInMonths)

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/HON5Z8OywQe

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you set monthDiff back to zero once your month reaches twelve.

```
monthsDiff = 0
// i.e. a.Month() is 10
// then subtract daysDiff with days of Month 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, and so on.
for _, daysInMonth := range daysInMonths[a.Month()-1:] {
    daysDiff -= float64(daysInMonth)
    if daysDiff < 0 {
        daysDiff += float64(daysInMonth)
        break
    }

    if monthDiff == 12 {
        monthsDiff = 0
    } else {
        monthsDiff += 1
    }

}
```

Comment: the monthDiff variable appears to be unused. The loop will also still only go from month to end and not wrap around. Can you explain more how this works?

Comment: The reason is that more than 12 should go to the year difference, but less than that difference will be in the month(s). Setting to Zero because, let's say, you started in March; after 12 iterations, you will be back in March.

Comment: @TheFool monthDiff is used, it is returned by the method. If you check the method signature in GitHub link.

Comment: That function has `named return values`.

Comment: @a_a the monthsDiff should not be reset to 0. The whole idea is to `subtract daysDiff with daysInMonth and add +1 to monthsDiff everytime you subtract it`. Kindly check the [full code](https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/cipta_integrasi_nusantara_backend/blob/master/calculateage/helper.go). But I get the idea why you would reset `monthsDiff = 0`. In theory, the monthsDiff will never be more than 11.

Comment: @kidfrom can you share your inputs and expected output

Comment: @a_a a user input date of birth "28-10-1983", the input should be "38 years, 11 months, 6 days" if the request was made in October 03, 2022.